# How do i heal my dogs

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How do I heal my dogs they took some damage jumping off a cliff (fall damage)?  I didn't know they were following me, can I heal them??

Comment: Right-click with any food item

Comment: @craftern3rdgurl, a lot of your questions can be answered by looking in the wiki. Please do some research before asking these types of questions. Wiki: http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Minecraft_Wiki

Answer (score 5):

According to the [Wiki's entry on wolves](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Dog#Taming.2C_health_and_feeding), you can heal your dogs by feeding them any non-fish meat (right click while holding out the the meat, pointing at the dog). The amount of health they recover will be equal to the hunger restored if eaten by the player.

Additionally, you can use a splash potion of healing (or regeneration) to quickly heal both the dogs and yourself.

Comment: Also note that the wolves health is shown by the angle of the tail.